# Find a shortest path in a maze and make a move

Tags: c++, maze

I am working on a rouge game and one of my monsters behaves like this.
In a maze, if monster can reach the player in 15 or less steps, it makes the most optimal move possible. In order to implement this, I wrote a small program mimicing basically what is going to happend in my game. My program works in a way that it is able to check if x ammount of moves will get him to destination.
The only part I am not sure is how to get the first step, so I can pass that info to my monster move function. Here is the program that I wrote so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



bool pathExists(char maze[][10], int sr, int sc, int er, int ec, int distance)
{
    if (maze[sr][sc] != '.')
        return false;

    if (sr == er  &&  sc == ec)
        return true;

    if(distance ==15)
    {
        cout<<"Cant make it in 15 steps"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    maze[sr][sc] = '@';  // anything non-'.' will do

    if (pathExists(maze, sr-1, sc, er, ec, distance+1))
        return true;
    if (pathExists(maze, sr+1, sc, er, ec,distance+1))
        return true;
    if (pathExists(maze, sr, sc-1, er, ec, distance+1))
        return true;
    if (pathExists(maze, sr, sc+1, er, ec, distance+1))
        return true;

    return false;
}





int main()
{
    char maze[10][10] = {
        { 'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','X','X','X','X','.','X','X','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','X','.','X','.','.','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','X','.','.','.','X','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','X','X','.','X','X','X','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','X','.','.','.','.','X','X','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','X','X','.','X','X','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','x','.','.','.','.','.','X'},
        { 'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'}
    };

    if (pathExists(maze, 8,8, 1,1,0))
        cout << "Solvable!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Out of luck!" << endl;
}
```

Just to summarize, I am looking to acquire the information about the very first step that this monster does. I know its kinda easy thing to ask, but I am new to recursions and kinda got lost in my code.

Thank you gods of c++.

Comment: I see many problems with this code. First, I see no bounds checking. The code will appear to try to advance to the nearest cell below, above, to the left, and to the right of the current cell, even if the current cell is on the edge of playing field. Finally, after marking the current cell as visited, and trying, unsuccessfully to move to every four directions, the current cell remains marked as being visited. That's also definitely wrong. Consider the code moving top to bottom, then to the right, when the "monster" is on the left. You just cut yourself off, even if you had enough moves left.

Comment: shortest path is found using [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: That is strange, because upon testing it seemed to work just fine. Did you tried to test it ?

Comment: That's not going to generate the *shortest* path, but the *first* path according to the way you iterate recursively over the paths with a distance less than `15`. It is possible that there is a path with distance `1` and you will generate a path with distance `15`. You should implement *Dijkstra's algorithm*.

Comment: Can someone point me to a webpage with a good explanation of Dijksra`s algorithm ? I learned some thins about it in my Discrete math course, but I forgot everything I new about it.

Comment: WhosCraig, I think I am blind, what link ? I cant see any links posted.

Comment: Note that Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm may not always give you optimal moves.

Comment: A rouge game? Is that, like, a game without any colours other than red?

Comment: @user1335175: It's the text that appears in blue, and causes your mouse cursor to turn into a hand when you hover over it. Not being funny but perhaps learn how to use the World Wide Web before attempting to create a computer game.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maze shortest path using recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466403/maze-shortest-path-using-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

Go with a* algorithm. Although you need to figure out wall collision. But since you are using grid, I would say go with A* algorithm. Wikipedia has explained the algorithm.(pseudo code )

You will need to work with vectors since its c++. 
If you still don't understand code on wikipedia then you can use a library that I had made few months ago. (Not kinda a library but you can call it a similar code. You will have to change few values to make it work. I had made it 20x20 maze ; you need 10x10)

Comment: Try to make it yourself. If in the end you need help comment here I will send link to my library.

Comment: Here: link to that cpp file    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-kdfhQ6GCH8LUdYVjZkX3lXZVE/edit?usp=docslist_api