# Maze shortest path using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, maze

First of all I want to note that I posted this same question before and did not found a right answer, so sorry for repeating question.

Note that I am required to use recursion here. I am aware that shortest path is usually found using BFS, which is not recursive, but I need to know how can this be done recursively.

I am working on a rouge game and one of my monsters behaves like this. In a maze, if monster can reach the player in 15 or less steps, it makes the most optimal move possible. In order to implement this, I wrote a small program mimicking basically what is going to happen in my game. My program works in a way that it is able to check if x amount of moves will get him to destination. The only part I am not sure is how to get the first step, so I can pass that info to my monster move function. Here is the program that I wrote so far.

One of my fellow students suggests to fill the empty space with different values and find the path that way, but I could not understand what he meant. Can someone explain to me how this can be done?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



bool pathExists(char maze[][10], int sr, int sc, int er, int ec, int distance) {
    if (maze[sr][sc] != '.')
        return false;

    if (sr == er  &&  sc == ec)
        return true;

    if(distance == 15) {
        cout<<"Cant make it in 15 steps"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    maze[sr][sc] = '@';  // anything non-'.' will do

    if (pathExists(maze, sr-1, sc, er, ec, distance+1))
        return true;
    if (pathExists(maze, sr+1, sc, er, ec,distance+1))
        return true;
    if (pathExists(maze, sr, sc-1, er, ec, distance+1))
        return true;
    if (pathExists(maze, sr, sc+1, er, ec, distance+1))
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main() {
    char maze[10][10] = {
        { 'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','X','X','X','X','.','X','X','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','X','.','X','.','.','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','X','.','.','.','X','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','X','X','.','X','X','X','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','X','.','.','.','.','X','X','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','X','X','.','X','X','.','X'},
        { 'X','.','.','x','.','.','.','.','.','X'},
        { 'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'}
    };

    if (pathExists(maze, 8,8, 1,1,0))
        cout << "Solvable!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Out of luck!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean *fill* in place of *feel*. I would also suggest removing extra blank lines in your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: You should pass a variable maze to your recursive function (not a common (global) one) and you may interpret '@' as visited.

Comment: You had got an [appropriate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30433998/1413395) to your previous question, so it's completely unclear, why you're asking again, and where and **why** you want to use _recursion_ actually. Looks like a simple loop for checking would do.

Comment: As a note, your distance check shouldnt write, because the thing it's writing is 100% wrong.  When that condition is reached, that means _this particular path that it checked_ didn't reach the player.  Not that no path reaches the player.   It can be triggered up to 1073741824 times.

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm works well.  The only thing missing is to restore the `'.'` in `pathExist()` if the tested path is not successful :

```
    ...
    if(pathExists(maze, sr, sc + 1, er, ec, distance + 1))
        return true;

    maze[sr][sc] = '.'; //<===========  add this to restore the maze state

    return false;
    }
```

Without this line, your failed attempts to find the right path will fill the array with `'@'` so that subsequent exploration will not find any praticable '.' anymore.

By the way,  the maze that you've posted in your question is not solvable in less than 15 attempts, because of the `'x'` in position `[8][3]`.

**Additional comment:**

You've also asked how this work.  In fact, your recursive algorithm without the trick of the '@' has no memory.  So in the recursive call, it doesn't remember were it came from, which will result in infinite recursion accrding to the following pattern:
[image]
The fact of changing the current position temporarily to '@' is as if you'd mark the different cells of the path currently being explored:
[image]

Note that if you print out the grid at the end, you'll see the full path that was found (with the problematic 'x' removed):
[image]

Comment: It's not actually infinitely recursive due to the max depth check.  It's just really, really, slow.  It's checking... 4^15 = 1073741824 different paths.

Comment: Oh yes !  It's capped to 15 ! "Infinite" is anyway somewhat abusive given the finite stack  ;-)   With the marker trick the first position has 4 possibilities, all other positions have max 3 possibilities, and at least one ahas no more than 2. That's 4*2*3^13.  So only 12754584 combinations left :-D

Comment: His _algorithm_ checks a _maximum_ of 1073741824 paths.  Less if it encounters a wall.  Since the grid is effectively 8x8, the actual number checked for any particular maze will be (significantly) less than that maximum.

Comment: @MooingDuck Did you take into account in your combinatorial analysis the path pruning that takes place in his algortihm ?

Comment: Thank you, it works, but the only problem that I am having here at the moment is that my algorithm does not nececeraly finds the shortest path. how can I fix this ?

Comment: My bad, it actually works. Interestingly the distance check determines if it takes a longer path or a shorter path. In case if I want to always get the shortest path what should I do? the only idea that I have is loop trough incrementing values of distance and run the algorithm multiple times

Comment: Yes, adding one more argument to a function and iterating the function with incrementing values all the way up to the limit seems to do the job.

Comment: If you need the shortest, and not just the first matching path, you have to explore all possible candidates.  Thre are several possibilities, but the easy one, is to return form pathExist the length of the shortest path.  Here an [online demo](http://ideone.com/iQyPbs).

Answer (score 0):

*The only part I am not sure is how to get the first step, so I can pass that info to my monster move function. Here is the program that I wrote so far.*

A possible way would be to return a code for the next step from the function if the path exists, otherwise 0 (although this might not be a recommended way for readable code, but just to propose the idea)

```
int pathExists(char maze[][10], int sr, int sc, int er, int ec, int distance) {
    if (maze[sr][sc] != '.')
        return 0; //

    if (sr == er  &&  sc == ec)
        return 5; // we are there

    if(distance == 15) {
        cout<<"Cant make it in 15 steps"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    maze[sr][sc] = '@';  // anything non-'.' will do

    if (pathExists(maze, sr-1, sc, er, ec, distance+1))
        return -1; // move north
    if (pathExists(maze, sr+1, sc, er, ec,distance+1))
        return 1; // move south
    if (pathExists(maze, sr, sc-1, er, ec, distance+1))
        return -2; // move west
    if (pathExists(maze, sr, sc+1, er, ec, distance+1))
        return 2; // move east

    maze[sr][sc] = '.'; // restore the maze, as in the previous answer
    return 0;
}
```